# why does strtotime('-1') return a timestamp one hour forward in time?

Tags: php, strtotime

Recently I created a bug where I wrote `$object->expiry = strtotime('-1')` causing the object to expire 1 hour from now instead of never. What I should have done is to set the expiry without `strtotime` like so `$object->expiry = -1`.

This bug got me thinking, **why does `strtotime('-1')` return a timestamp that is one hour forward in time?**

And likewise, **why does `strtotime('+1')` return a timestamp one hour back in time?**

It would make sense to me if the opposite happened so why does `strtotime()` work in this way?

Comment: Garbage in, Garbage out comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) uses the rules described in the ["Supported Date and Time Formats"](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) documentation page to parse the input string.

The date and time components that are not present in the input string are initialized using the current time.

The input strings `'-1'` and `'+1'` do not contain any date or time. The parser interprets them as timezone corrections.

What you get is you current local time with the timezone changed to `UTC-1` or `UTC+1`. The returned value depends on the timezone of your server.

It is one hour in the future or one hour in the past only if the timezone of your server is set to `UTC`. Otherwise, when you format the value as local time, the value you get contains your local timezone offset applied twice.

For example, my local timezone is `UTC+2` and my local time now is `2018-03-15 13:24:20 +0200`

For reference, the current UTC time and local time:

```
$ php -r 'echo(gmdate("r"));'
# Thu, 15 Mar 2018 11:24:20 +0000
$ php -r 'echo(date("r"));'
# Thu, 15 Mar 2018 13:24:20 +0200
```

This is what `strtotime('-1');` produces:

```
$ php -r 'echo(date("r", strtotime("-1")));'
# Thu, 15 Mar 2018 16:24:21 +0200
$ php -r 'echo(date("r", strtotime("+1")));'
# Thu, 15 Mar 2018 14:24:27 +0200
```

`strtotime("-1")` is not 1 hour in the future but 3 hours. One hour because of `'-1'` plus two hours because of `UTC+2`.

The difference is bigger if you use an Asian timezone (bigger positive offset). It produces dates in the past if you use negative offsets (Americas).

Comment: That's a good answer and really interesting. You learn something new every day.